# Create a virtual MIDI port

Tags: driver, midi, wdk, winmm

I want to create a virtual MIDI loopback cable program that  creates virtual MIDI ports to interconnect applications on Windows that want to open hardware-MIDI-ports for communication.

SOrry if I am not clear in my requirements, here is an example application that does what I intend to do.

http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/loopMIDI.html

How do I go about this? Any tips or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can read a lot about how to do this right on the web site you linked under "virtualMIDI"!

Comment: Oops... Somehow, I never noticed that... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ok, so VirtualMIDI source code is not available. I mailed Tobias erichsen, and I did not get any response. I am going to start a bounty on this, just to see if I can get somewhere.

Comment: @ashwnacharya: use IDA to look at the code for the driver that does it to find out where to start.

Answer (score 1):

After many nights of searching, the best way I have found is to actually use Tobias Erichsen's driver.

His driver works quite well, and if you e-mail him, he will provide you with the API necessary.

Comment: His driver works perfectly for that matter. I just wanted to know how it works, and if possible, code it myself using C# for the learning experience.

Comment: @ashwnacharya, writing a driver in C# isn't possible.  Please see Hans' answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954552/ddk-hello-world

Comment: FWIW, I am open to doing a lot of PInvokes and DLLImports if that's what it takes.

Comment: @ashwnacharya, sure, but you can't create a driver with PInvoke.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463268

Comment: @ashwnacharya: I have to side with Brad. Though the problem isn't really the language, but the structure/contents of the resulting binary and its dependendies. First of all drivers don't have a subsystem set in the PE header. Secondly, they don't depend on any Win32 binaries. Since .NET is based in the Win32 subsystem it will simply fail at this point already. Besides, driver development takes a whole lot of foresight and insight. One does not simply walk into kernel mode without preliminary knowledge. Please take no offense, but your comments make it obvious that you lack that knowledge.

Comment: No offense taken. I would be the first person to admit that I am clueless when it comes to driver development. Just exploring to see if there is anything I can do.

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 the TE driver won't work for me. Tried changing group policy on unsigned drivers too but nop not functional. It errors. I suspect the driver signing problem is to blame.

Comment: As an outsider to this problem: how can the answer be that only one man knows the answer? How did he learn about it?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but this link had some sound advice on how to get started. Leaving this here in case anyone else is also interested.
http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=20#Q25

Comment: Note that as of the time of this comment, that link is locked behind a forum registration.