# MIDI sniffing + OpenGL in Windows

Tags: opengl, windows-7, midi

I'm currently specing out projects for my graphics class and I am thinking of writing an application that displays a visualizer for midi data.  What I would like to do is sniff midi data as it passes through the system.  I do not want to hijack a driver, only watch the data go by (that is, I want the MIDI data to later be accessible by a DAW).  I am not familiar with programatically accessing midi in windows.  The closest I could find to what I want seems to be [midi spy](https://github.com/hiben/MIDISpy).  However I would prefer to write the app in c/c++.

I was looking at [MIDI Stream API](http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/stream.htm), but I can't tell if I'll be able to sniff devices that weren't opened by the library.  I was also looking at [SDL Mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) and [QT Midi](http://qt-project.org/search/tag/midi).  I'm just trying to get some personal pros and cons to the options that I've presented or ones that I haven't found.

Comment: This question should not be closed.  It is a very clear, focused question with a specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to actually sniff MIDI streams under Windows.  All you can do is place your application between the two MIDI devices.

Unless you are putting software between physical in/out ports, you will need to set up a virtual MIDI loopback driver that directs the MIDI stream data from an input to an output.  Fortunately, there are a few off-the-shelf solutions already.  The easiest method is to require your users to set up a virtual MIDI port and configure it on their own.  [LoopBe1](http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html) and [MIDI Yoke](http://www.midiox.com/) are free.

Another method is to use a virtual MIDI driver that goes directly to your application.  [Tobias Erichsen](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software.html) has created a very easy-to-use driver for this very purpose.  I don't believe he has released it yet, but if you shoot him an e-mail, he might get back to you.  See this question:  [DDK "Hello World"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3954552/362536)

Comment: I just so happen to have LoopBe30. So I just have to open a new midi port, and connect them via LoopBe?